# Invert of Matrix I-BA

Tags: matrices

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two square Matrix. Let $I-AB$ be invertible. I would like to know why $I-BA$ is also invertible? Also what is invert of $I-BA$? Thanks.

Comment: this is a duplicate

Comment: usually you link the duplicate not just say.

Comment: @user1709828 Sometimes it's difficult to find the other question.

Comment: Thank you very much for all answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(I-BA)(I+B(I-AB)^{-1}A)=I$$ here $I$  is the identity matrix

so $(I-BA)^{-1}= I+B(I-AB)^{-1}A$

Comment: This is a special case of the Sherman–Morrison–Woodbury-Justin-Bieber formula.

Comment: how did Justin-Bieber come into formula?

Comment: Damn, that guy is everywhere nowadays...

Comment: I'm just impressed he gets to have his first and last name in the formula. Never seen that before.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: well, jim just gave you the formula. But if you want to play the game, the hint I give you is a fun way to manipulate expressions which do not a priori make sense to compute a formula which really works. And that's probably like that that the fact and the formula were discovered.

Hint: pretend that the Neumann series of $(I-BA)^{-1}$ converges and use it to make the Neumann series of $(I-AB)^{-1}$ appear. You'll get a formula giving you a candidate for $(I-BA)^{-1}$. Just check that it works.

Answer (score 3):

Wait, here is another approach:

The non-zero eigenvalues of $AB$ and $BA$ are the same (If $ABv= \lambda v$, then $B(AB)v = (BA) (Bv) = \lambda (Bv)$, and since $Bv \neq 0$, we see that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $BA$).

Since $I-AB$ is invertible, this means that $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $AB$, and hence not of $BA$ either. Hence $I-BA$ is invertible.

Comment: Ok, +1, but this do not gives the inverse.

Comment: That's funny. Usually, I use that $1-ab$ is invertible if and only if $1-ba$ is invertible to conclude that the spectum of $ab$ minus $0$ is the same as the spectrum of $ba$ minus $0$ in a general Banach algebra.

Comment: @sbr: I missed that originally, and my only different proof is a block matrix version of jim's solution below.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/sylvester-determinant-identity/) should contain all of the information you might want--probably more.